# Use Vue3 components/routing in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, vuejs3

My task is migrate incrementally from AngularJS to Vue3. The idea is to start using Vue components in some places, rotes, server requests.

Is someone has success story using Vue3 components/routing in AngularJS project?

I've spent few days trying make it work, but in internet there is no example about it. Only Vue2/AngularIO, Vue3/AngularIO, Vue2/AngularJS, etc.

Not sure what more information I need to provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to mix two different frameworks? This sounds like a recipe for problems.

Comment: Hi @Thomas! My task is migrate incrementally from AngularJS to Vue3. I'll put this information into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think one good way to achieve such a complex migration would be to borrow some principles from the microfrontend architecture principle.
Just divide your application in big components, that you would like to convert one by one.

Take a big component of your application, rewrite it in VueJS, and make it communicate to the rest of your application using custom events.

That will allow you to work incrementally, without using any additional component or library to make the transition.

Just be sure to define clearly the boundaries between your different components, and don't try to apply this approach to very small components (as there will be some overhead involved by adding this event communication).